# My Anchor Hyperlink is not working unless zoomed in

Tags: html, css, href

I have a code that is working but href (link) is not displaying unless zoomed in, is there something I'm missing ? 
Here is my code(I replace img source with "imagelink" for security reasons but I have correct src):

```html
<div class="socialMediaDiv" style="">
  <a href="#"><img src="imagelink" style="max-width: 35px;"><span style="margin-left: 5%; color: black;">Fresh Member Facebook Group</span></a>
</div>

<div class="socialMediaDiv" style="padding-top: 3%;">
  <a href="#"><img src="imagelink" style="max-width: 35px;"><span style="margin-left: 5%; color: black;">Fresh Networking Facebook Page</span></a>
</div>

<div class="socialMediaDiv" style="padding-top: 3%;">
  <a href="#"><img src="#" style="max-width: 35px;"><span style="margin-left: 5%; color: black;">Fresh Member Events Facebook Group</span></a>
</div>

<div class="socialMediaDiv" style="padding-top: 3%;">
  <a href="#"><img src="imagelink" style="max-width: 35px;"><span style="margin-left: 5%; color: black;">Fresh Networking Instagram</span></a>
</div>

<div class="socialMediaDiv" style="padding-top: 3%;">
  <a href="#"><img src="imagelink" style="max-width: 35px;"><span style="margin-left: 5%; color: black;">Fresh Member LinkedIn</span></a>
</div>

<div class="socialMediaDiv" style="padding-top: 3%;">
  <a href="#"><img src="imagelink" style="max-width: 35px;"><span style="margin-left: 5%; color: black;">Fresh Networking YouTube</span></a>
</div>

<div class="socialMediaDiv" style="padding-top: 3%;">
  <a href="#"><img src="imagelink" style="max-width: 35px;"><span style="margin-left: 5%; color: black;">Fresh HQ (Only for Leadership Members)</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the ```socialMediaDiv``` class? It sounds like a media query is possibly hiding the link when you zoom in/change the screen size?

Comment: @Andrew I did inspect, it only does some css styling.

Comment: I don't believe there's anything in the code provided that suggests this kind of behavior. Using the browser's devtools are you able to resize your screen to identify at which pixel the links disappear?

Answer (score -1):

Impossible to know the source of the problem when we don't have the context and full CSS source. Link doesn't lead to anything (#) anyway but I guess you have replaced it in the example.

The culprit is probably CSS. Try narrow it down by removing the related code. Could be overflow issue or some other alignment issue.